# eventListener on form is not firing

Tags: javascript

I've copied some code from a tutorial, which sends form content to an API. The API is set up on AWS and works if I send it some JSON using Postman. However the JavaScript isn't working. When I hit the submit button on the form the sendDataToLambda function is not executing. If I add onClick="sendDataToLambda()" to the submit button then the function fires (but then fails on the e.preventDefault() line, which is expected behavior).

I've checked the form ID is correct and that the listener is set up correctly and I can't find the fault.
I prefer not to use jQuery if at all possible.

```html
<body>
    <div class=container>
        <h1>Notes</h1>

        <form id="note-form" style="margin-top:50px;">
            <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Enter subject here…" class="form-control" /><br/>
            <textarea id="body" rows="3" placeholder="Enter body here…" class="form-control"></textarea><br/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Adds an event listener to our form. When the form is submitted, it will send data to our Lambda function, which in turn, will send us an email.
        document.getElementById('note-form').addEventListener('submit', sendDataToLambda);

        // Now for the good stuff. This is the function that will send our data to AWS.
        function sendDataToLambda(e) {
            console.log('Submit clicked')
            e.preventDefault();

            // Gets the values of each field in our form. This is the data we'll send to our Lambda function.
            var formSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
            var formBody = document.getElementById('body').value;

            // This is the endpoint we created in our API Gateway. This is where we make our POST request, which calls our Lambda function.
            var endpoint = 'https://################';

            // Remember those form values we just grabbed? We're going to put them into an object here.
            var body = {
                subject: formSubject,
                body: formBody
            }

            // Here, we instantiate our Request. This is a special object used by the Fetch API so it knows where to send data, what data to send, and how to send it.
            var lambdaRequest = new Request(endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                // Quick note: 'no-cors' mode is for development on localhost only!
                mode: 'no-cors',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });

            // Call the Fetch API to make our request
            fetch(lambdaRequest)
            // This is where you can handle errors. This is just an example, so we won't cover that.
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have an `<input type="submit">` so... it won't trigger `onsubmit`.

Comment: Change type="button": `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Submit</button>`

Comment: Thank you, changed the button type and now works! Wow my first ajax !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `onSubmit` event to fire, you need to make sure your form has a submit button (must have the [type attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) set to `submit`).

```html
<button type="submit" ... >Submit</button>
```

See the code below for the modifications to your code:

```html
<body>
    <div class=container>
        <h1>Notes</h1>

        <form id="note-form" style="margin-top:50px;">
            <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Enter subject here…" class="form-control" /><br/>
            <textarea id="body" rows="3" placeholder="Enter body here…" class="form-control"></textarea><br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Adds an event listener to our form. When the form is submitted, it will send data to our Lambda function, which in turn, will send us an email.
        document.getElementById('note-form').addEventListener('submit', sendDataToLambda);

        // Now for the good stuff. This is the function that will send our data to AWS.
        function sendDataToLambda(e) {
            console.log('Submit clicked')
            e.preventDefault();

            // Gets the values of each field in our form. This is the data we'll send to our Lambda function.
            var formSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
            var formBody = document.getElementById('body').value;

            // This is the endpoint we created in our API Gateway. This is where we make our POST request, which calls our Lambda function.
            var endpoint = 'https://################';

            // Remember those form values we just grabbed? We're going to put them into an object here.
            var body = {
                subject: formSubject,
                body: formBody
            }

            // Here, we instantiate our Request. This is a special object used by the Fetch API so it knows where to send data, what data to send, and how to send it.
            var lambdaRequest = new Request(endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                // Quick note: 'no-cors' mode is for development on localhost only!
                mode: 'no-cors',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });

            // Call the Fetch API to make our request
            fetch(lambdaRequest)
            // This is where you can handle errors. This is just an example, so we won't cover that.
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```